# Cannot refresh QT's view while changing model

Tags: qt, qml

I am learning how to integrate qml with c++.
I've implemented a custom model class **StringListModel**, which inherits **QAbstratListModel**.
And, I have a main.qml to use **StringListModel**.
QML view can show initial values correctly.
I have another thread to change model periodically.
I do use beginResetModel() and endResetModel() to indicate model changed.

However, while the model keeps been changed, the view didn't update.

Here is my source code.
Please teach me what went wrong.
THANKS!

=== main.qml ===

```
Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360

    Grid {
        id: gridview
        columns: 2
        spacing: 20

        Repeater {
            id: repeater
            model: StringListModel {
            id:myclass
        }

        delegate: Text {
            text: model.title
        }
    }
}
```

=== custom class.h ===

```
class StringListModel : public QAbstractListModel{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    StringListModel(QObject *parent = 0);

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const;

    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;

    void newItem();
private:
    QStringList stringList;

};


class UpdateThread : public QThread {
    Q_OBJECT

    StringListModel *mMyClass;

public:
    UpdateThread(StringListModel * myClass);
protected:
    void run();
};
```

=== custom class.cpp ===

```
StringListModel::StringListModel(QObject *parent) : QAbstractListModel(parent)
{
    stringList << "one" << "two" << "three";
    QThread *thread = new UpdateThread(this);
    thread->start();
}

int StringListModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return stringList.count();
}

QVariant StringListModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();

    if (index.row() >= stringList.size())
        return QVariant();

    if (role == Qt::UserRole + 1)
        return stringList.at(index.row());
    else
        return QVariant();
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> StringListModel::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[Qt::UserRole + 1] = "title";

    return roles;
}
void StringListModel::newItem()
{
    qDebug() << "size: " << stringList.size();
    beginResetModel();
    stringList << "new";
    endResetModel();
}

UpdateThread::UpdateThread(StringListModel * myClass)
{
    mMyClass = myClass;
}

void UpdateThread::run()
{
    while (true) {
        mMyClass->newItem();
        msleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: That won't work, QAbstractItemModel isn't thread-safe. Better send the data via signal/slot from the update thread to the main thread.

Comment: Hi Frank,
Thank you for your solution.
After read article about signal/slot, I finally solved this problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're dutifully ignoring the matters of synchronizing access to the model. When you have *any* object that's accessed from more than one thread (even something as "simple" as a raw pointer), you must deal with the ramifications of such access.

I suggest you don't mess with threads unless you have measurements showing that you'll benefit.